# Where is the org contrib directory?

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to use `org-checklist`. The [documentation](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-checklist.html) says that I should 'Ensure the org contrib directory is in load-path'. Where is the contrib directory?

Answer (score 9):

Checking out the git version of Org, it's in [`./contrib`](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/contrib).  To install contrib, you could use [Org ELPA](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html).  As pointed out by Erik, you should get the `org-plus-contrib` package from Org ELPA.

You could also use a git-checkout, see [*Keeping Current*](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#keeping-current-with-Org-mode-development) and [more on installing Org](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-build-system.html).

Comment: Note that with Org ELPA you have to install the `org-plus-contrib` package.  The `org` packages this and ELPA provide don't include the contrib packages.

Answer (score 3):

The location of the `contrib` directory depends on where you have `org-mode` installed.  A simple way to tell is to `M-x find-library RET org-contribdir`.  The commentary from the latter:

> The sole purpose of this file is to be located in the same place
>   as where the contributed Org files are located, typically in the
>   contrib/lisp directory of the Org-mode distribution.  This is to
>   make sure that the command `org-reload' can reliably locate
>   contributed org files.